# Java Max Heap Size (Xmx) not respected based on XX:printFlagsFinal

Tags: java, jvm, server, heap-memory

I configured a Java server to start with `-Xmx12288M` and `-Xmx12288M`; however when I go to the Java process and run this: `java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep -iE 'MaxHeapSize'`, I see the value as 4141875200 - which I believe is ~4GB.

I ran `jps -vl` and I do see `-Xmx12288M` there. Am I looking at the wrong place for the max heap size the process can use? Or is it actually not using the configured max heap size?

This is running on a 64bit JVM.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like: `java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep -iE 'MaxHeapSize'` starts a Java process and prints out the settings on it. It does not print the JVM settings from the running Java process.

This worked for me: `jinfo <pid-of-running-java-process> | grep 'HeapSize'`. This printed:

```
Non-default VM flags: ...  -XX:InitialHeapSize=12884901888 -XX:MaxHeapSize=12884901888 ...
```

Comment: Yes, this is the right answer.  Running java -version will start a new java process.

Answer (score 3):

> Am I looking at the wrong place for the max heap size the process can
>   use?

Yes, you are looking at the wrong place.  As @Aishwar points out, running `$java -version` creates a new Java process.  You could :

add the `PrintFlagsFinal` flag to your servers Java options and read the log file, or simply attach to your java process with a tool like jinfo or JVisualVM and inspect the usage.